# View showing members of a marketing list and the campaign

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to display the members of a marketing list alongside the name of the campaign.

So:

Campaign x:  Joe, Jane, Jose 
Campaign y:  Joe, John, Joanna

etc, etc.

I can get to the point of displaying the list link alongside the campaign title but that requires users to click through on list to see members, for our application we want to be able to see those list members directly in a view.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting request. You can write a plugin to give you a rollup of the list members as a comma-separated string which you can store in a text area field and display on a view.

I have created a plugin do this type of rollup in a few situations, but never to "flatten" an entire marketing list. If the list gets big, it'll get crazy.

As an alternative, maybe look into doing something with the Report Wizard to display the list members grouped by campaign.

Comment: Thanks Aron, appreciate the suggestions.